# Very long number sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Here is the sequence:

```
72, 101, 114, 101, 32, 105, 115, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 58, 32, 10, 10, 55, 50, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 51, 50, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 51, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 51, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 51, 44, 32, 49, 49, 55, 44, 32, ?
```

What is the question mark in the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is a fresh puzzle, though trivial if you know the right thing.

If you

> convert the numbers to ASCII characters with the character codes,

you get

> ```
> Here is the sequence:
>  
> 72, 101, 114, 101, 32, 105, 115, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 115, 101, 113, 117,
> ```
>
> with a trailing space

which makes the entire post

> self-referential.

Therefore, the next number is

> **49**, the character code for `1`.

Comment: [Related sequence](https://oeis.org/A109648).